# one way and two ways anova

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, interaction, teaching

anova can be used to test the influence of a factor on an output.

One way anova is used if we are considering only one factor and two ways anova can be used if we are considering two factors.

Suppose to test the hypothesis H0 : a1=a2=a3=0
I would like a simulated example where the  one way anova return a wrong result and the two ways anova return a correct result.

This can be achieved introducing a second variable b that has some interaction with a.

A simulated example with R code would be the perfect answer.

Comment: Try search for interaction in ANOVA, you should find some examples on results like [this one](http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/multibook/mlt09.htm). The page provides all means and SD, you should be able to make an R data set using that info.

Comment: (1) This sounds a lot like [routine bookwork](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), as might be set for an assignment. (How does this question arise?) $\quad$ (2) You might find the discussion (and the diagram) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) useful.

Comment: I have to prepare a presentation on anova for non technical people and I think that a  simulated can be very useful. It would be good also to me to understand better how anova works.